# About gcc-compiled x86_64 code and C code optimization

Tags: c, optimization, gcc, x86, x86-64

I compiled the following C code:

```
typedef struct {
    long x, y, z;
} Foo;

long Bar(Foo *f, long i)
{
    return f[i].x + f[i].y + f[i].z;
}
```

with the command `gcc -S -O3 test.c`. Here is the Bar function in the output:

```
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .globl  _Bar
    .align  4, 0x90
_Bar:
Leh_func_begin1:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp0:
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp1:
    leaq    (%rsi,%rsi,2), %rcx
    movq    8(%rdi,%rcx,8), %rax
    addq    (%rdi,%rcx,8), %rax
    addq    16(%rdi,%rcx,8), %rax
    popq    %rbp
    ret
Leh_func_end1:
```

I have a few questions about this assembly code:

1. What is the purpose of "`pushq %rbp`", "`movq %rsp, %rbp`", and "`popq %rbp`", if neither `rbp` nor `rsp` is used in the body of the function?
2. Why do `rsi` and `rdi` automatically contain the arguments to the C function (`i` and `f`, respectively) without reading them from the stack?
3. I tried increasing the size of Foo to 88 bytes (11 `long`s) and the `leaq` instruction became an `imulq`. Would it make sense to design my structs to have "rounder" sizes to avoid the multiply instructions (in order to optimize array access)? The `leaq` instruction was replaced with:

   ```
   imulq   $88, %rsi, %rcx
   ```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The function is simply building its own stack frame with these instructions. There's nothing really unusual about them. You should note, though, that due to this function's small size, it will probably be inlined when used in the code. The compiler is always required to produce a "normal" version of the function, though. Also, what @ouah said in his answer.
2. This is because that's how the AMD64 ABI specifies the arguments should be passed to functions.

   > If the class is INTEGER, the next available register of the sequence
   >   %rdi, %rsi, %rdx, %rcx, %r8 and %r9 is used.

   Page 20, AMD64 ABI Draft 0.99.5 – September 3, 2010
3. This is not *directly* related to the structure size, rather - the absolute address that the function has to access. If the size of the structure is 24 bytes, `f` is the address of the array containing the structures, and `i` is the index at which the array has to be accessed, then the byte offset to each structure is `i*24`. Multiplying by 24 in this case is achieved by a combination of `lea` and SIB addressing. The first `lea` instruction simply calculates `i*3`, then every subsequent instruction uses that `i*3` and multiplies it further by 8, therefore accessing the array at the needed absolute byte offset, and then using immediate displacements to access the individual structure members (`(%rdi,%rcx,8)`. `8(%rdi,%rcx,8)`, and `16(%rdi,%rcx,8)`). If you make the size of the structure 88 bytes, there is simply no way of doing such a thing swiftly with a combination of `lea` and any kind of addressing. The compiler simply assumes that a simple `imull` will be more efficient in calculating `i*88` than a series of shifts, adds, `lea`s or anything else.

Comment: Yes I know all that. My question was is it worth padding the structure with extra space just to make it a "rounder" number (like 12 longs instead of 11 longs) which would avoid using a multiply in calculating the array index?

Comment: @Matt: no one can answer that in general - the padding doesn't come for free either (cache sizes); don't guess, measure!

Answer (score 2):

> 1. What is the purpose of pushq %rbp, movq %rsp, %rbp, and popq %rbp, if neither rbp nor rsp is used in the body of the function?

To keep track of the frames when you use a debugger. Add `-fomit-frame-pointer` to optimize (note that it should be enabled at `-O3` but in a lot of `gcc` versions I used it is not).

Answer (score 0):

```
3. I tried increasing the size of Foo to 88 bytes (11 longs) and the leaq instruction became an imulq. Would it make sense to design my structs to have "rounder" sizes to avoid the multiply instructions (in order to optimize array access)?
```

The leaq call is (essentially and in this cae) calculating k*a+b where "k" is 1, 2, 4, or 8 and "a" and "b" are registers. If "a" and "b" are the same, it can be used for structures of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, and 9 longs.

Larger structures like 16 longs *may* be optimizable by calculating the offset with for "k" and doubling, but I do not know if that is what the compiler will actually do; you would have to test.

Comment: I tried it with twelve and it does optimize it. ("`leaq    (%rsi,%rsi,2), %rcx`" and then "`shlq    $5, %rcx`") But my question was is it worth increasing the size lets say from 88 to 96 just to avoid a multiply during array access (assuming I will be doing a lot of array access).

Comment: Ah, sorry. If memory less important than performance and you can be confident that the imul will be avoided, then yes, I would. (Insert here the standard disclaimer about pre-optimizing and testing to verify.)